# MembershipUser is not working

Tags: asp.net

I m creating library for my test projects.
Namespace is not working when i create library project.
Please help

#region(GET LOGGED USER ID)

```
    static public Guid GetUserId()
    {
        Guid guUser = Guid.Empty;

        try
        {
            MembershipUser muUser = Membership.GetUser();
            if (muUser != null)
            {
                guUser = (Guid)muUser.ProviderUserKey;
                Membership.GetUser(guUser, true);
            }
            else
            {
                //Log out and redirect to login page
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationError.LogErrors(ex);
        }

        return guUser;
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work if tested in a unit test solution, because your unit test solution must have the same .config file as the final application project. Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: Just do it, but in your unit test project create a .config file and configure it the same way as your exe or web project.